# When i use repartition on a dataframe in pyspark it gives me one partition size to be zero and merges two types of keys together

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Here is an example of it. The cell 44 output shows the count of distinct keys but when i find the partition size in cell 45 then it combines together 3 and 5. also on saving the size of one partition is still zero. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spark applies a HashPartitioner to the values of the column `overint`. Apparently, the values `3` and `5` fall into the same partition after being hashed.

You may want to choose the RangePartitioner. Or, in case you need full flexibility, you could also write your custome `Partitioner` class. However, this is only available on the RDD API and not the Structured API.

Comment: I am unable to understand how they are going into the same partition after being hashed because currently it is combining 3 and 5 but the other day it was combining 1 and 2. Any way to calculate the hash code for the column values?